# find the common rows in 2 different dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm writing a function that needs to work with different datasets. The columns that have to be passed inside the function look somewhat like the following data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("d","e","f","g"),  x2 = c("Aug 2017","Sep 2017","Oct 2017","Nov 2017"),  x3 = c(456,678,876,987))

df2 <- data.frame(x1 = c("a","b","c","d"),  x2 = c("Aug 2017","Sep 2017","Oct 2017","Nov 2017"),  x3 = c(123,324,345,564))
```

From these I need to find out if any of the df1$x1 are present in df2$x2. If present, print the entire row where df1$x1 value that is present in df2$x2.

I need to use the data frames inside the function but I can't specify the column names explicitly. So I need to find a way to access the columns without exactly using the column name.

The desired output:

```
x1       x2     x3         x4

d    Aug 2017   456    common
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEYPo.png)

My problem is, I can't use any kind of function where I need to specify the column names explicitly. For example, inner join cannot be performed since I have to specify

```
by = 'col_name'
```

Comment: Do you mean that its always the first columns of df1 and df2 that you are checking?  Also, I think you mean where df1$x1 is present in df2$x1?

Comment: No, it's not always the first column. Yea sorry, it's df2$x1.

Comment: so, if it is not always the first column, then the function is receving the columns themselves, as vectors?.. You'll need to explain more -see @Maël solution below which, like me, assumed you would have to match on indices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three simple examples of functions that you might use to return the rows you want, where *the function itself* does not need to hardcode the name of the column, and does not require the indices to match:

1. Pass the frames directly, and the column names as strings:

```
f <- function(d1, d2, col1, col2) d1[which(d1[,col1] %in% d2[,col2]),]
```

Usage and Output

```
f(df1,df2, "x1", "x1")

  x1       x2  x3
1  d Aug 2017 456
```

2. Pass only the values of the columns as vectors:

```
f <- function(x,y) which(x %in% y)
```

Usage and Output

```
df1 %>% filter(row_number() %in% f(x1, df2$x1))

  x1       x2  x3
1  d Aug 2017 456
```

3. Pass the frames and the unquoted columns, using the `{{}}` operator

```
f <- function(d1, d2, col1, col2) {
  filter(d1, {{col1}} %in% pull(d2, {{col2}}))
}
```

Usage and Output:

```
f(df1,df2,x1,x1)

  x1       x2  x3
1  d Aug 2017 456
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` with column indices:

```r
df1[na.omit(match(df2[, 1], df1[, 1])), ]
#  x1       x2  x3
#1  d Aug 2017 456
```